# Exporting HTML Table data to Excel file in Angular10

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, xlsx

I am using Angular-10, with  XLSX and  file-saver library to export the data.
Its working properly for a single page export.When i used pagination at client side using "ngx-pagination", then i unable to export all the data in the single attempt, only paginated table can be exported.

Whenever pagination is enabled , i am unable to export the complete table data.
Since i am having array of arrays in my response , i am trying to export table-to -excel , instead of json to excel. But here also i am facing the problem, can anyone help me .

.ts Code:

```
exportUserListAsXLSX(){   
    this.dbAllUsersListsr.dbAllUsersList()
    .subscribe(
      data => 
      {
       this.userAllListExport = data;
        console.log(this.userAllListExport);
        this.UserExportDatasr.exportAsExcelFile(this.userAllListExport, 'UserExport');
      })
  }
```

service.ts

```
public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    
    let element = document.getElementById('excel-table');
    //const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(element)

    console.log('worksheet',worksheet);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    //const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
  }

  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
  }
}
```

Sample JSON Response from backend:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5ff378b3b4d09aa6",
    "userRefID": "07f426ff-5db-2c737edac61",
    "userName": "ES Team",
    "divisionId": "36852a81-a1cd-7f431c05179f",
    "divisionName": "",
    "emailId": "eps@ge.com",
    "__v": 0,
    "queues": [
      {
        "_id": "5ff378b354b4d09aa1",
        "userRefID": "07f426ff-5062c7397edac61",
        "queueRefId": "c02db2a-a9cd-0f16c823646b",
        "queueName": "test",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ff378b3145b3c54b4d09aa2",
        "userRefID": "07f426ff-506f-4e5e-afdb-2c7397edac61",
        "queueRefId": "a626d99e-f5e9-47ab-a5d0-d493003c737f",
        "queueName": "Ca",
        "__v": 0
      },
    ],
  },
{
    "_id": "5ff378b34d09aa7",
    "userRefID": "c5ce06dc-628-f5fc5a918295",
    "userName": "neric",
    "divisionId": "36852a81-ad7f7f431c05179f",
    "divisionName": "",
    "emailId": "intebeb45b9d295@webhook.com",
    "__v": 0,
    "queues": [
      {
        "_id": "5ff378b3154b4d9aeb",
        "userRefID": "c5ce06dc-f5fc5a98295",
        "queueRefId": "f3bf0897f-5b18fc03401b",
        "queueName": "Aseem",
        "__v": 0
      },
      
    ],
  }
]
```

Thanks,